# How to fix 404 error Node JS Express POST Request

Tags: javascript, forms, express, post

I am trying to submit the following html form to a js file:

```
                        <form action="/submit-form" method="POST">


                             <input type="text" name="username">

                             <button> Click Here Now </button>


                        </form>
```

Here´s the file I want to submit it to. I've tried moving folders around, changing ports, and nothing seems to work.

```
          var express = require('express');

          var app = express();
          
          app.listen(80, function(){ 

           console.log("Hello whatsup");

         })
         app.post('/submit-form', function(req,response){

              console.log("All great");
    
          })
```

Both files are on my Xampp htdocs folder, specifically located inside a folder that contains made for this particular project. It contains the package.json files, the node_modules folder, the js file and the html form.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit to a file"? Where did you place the html file? Where did you place the js file? Where is all this running? How did you start the nodejs server?

Comment: I have both the html file and the js file where I want to receive the post request inside my htdocs local server folder. Im running the js file on my windows command line with nodemon. By submit I mean send the information in the html form to the JS file in order to process it.

Comment: What "htdocs local server folder" are you talking about? Do you have another webserver running besides the nodejs application? And how (under which url) do you load the page in your browser)?

Comment: Is the HTML snippet hosted on the same Node server?

Comment: Sorry. I will try to clarify all of those details in the main post right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're just running form locally with no kind of hosting/rendering then you need to specify the url for it to know how to hit your local server.

Example 1:

Using your code example but modified slightly to use non-relative path

Let's say you create a file `index.html` in your machine and open it through browser with the following contents per your example above

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/submit-form" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <button> Click Here Now </button>
</form>
```

The above assumes your server is setup as follows with port 8080. All I did was modify the port in your code

Let's say you have a server.js file that you start as `node server.js`. NOTE: This assumes that you already have express in your node_modules

```
      var express = require('express');

      var app = express();
      
      app.listen(8080, function(){ 

       console.log("Hello whatsup");

      })
      app.post('/submit-form', function(req,response){
          console.log("All great");

      })
```

Example 2:

Using your code example to explain relative path

If you are hosting both the server and client in the same server for which the url used for your index.html is the same as the url used for your server. Then you can use the relative path as you had it

```
<form action="/submit-form" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <button> Click Here Now </button>
</form>
```

Since this will look for the domain that you are rendering from. Let's say you are rendering and end up with a domain http://awesomeurl.com, then when your form hits /submit-form it will then call `http://awesomeurl.com/submit-form` with the POST request. If your server is also hosted and exposed with same url, then it will all work.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Unfortunately it keeps failing for me though. I have the js file in which I want to process the form and the form itself as sister files (or parallel  on the same folder level) . I have tried doing it with both relative and absolute paths, for some reason it happens to work on my mac, but not on my windows computer.

Comment: ok, I just saw you updated to using Xampp as your server for serving the html. Xampp and express servers are two different things. Xampp will be serving your html code in one port, and express will be serving it in another depending on what you set. So I would use non-relative path in this case. As for why it doesn't work in windows, it's a bit difficult to know without looking at logs. It would be good to take a look at your developer tools in browser console to figure out what endpoint and path is being hit when running in windows vs mac and go from there.

Comment: Is it possible to serve the html form in express?

Comment: You can but I would suggest either using a templating setup like ejs to render. Here is a tutorial that will show you how to send the html files for your testing and also mentioned how to render templating files in express https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/

Comment: I was finally able to fix it by turning off the Xampp server and just using Express! Thank you so much for your help!